# What happens if I close my android application without closing an open realm instance?

Tags: android, realm

I have kept a single realm instance opened on main thread in `Application` class and I use that single instance to do all kinds of DB operations from `MainActivity`. Since my application has a single activity, I close the instance in the activity's `onDestroy()`. The app is working fine for me as of now.

What are the repercussions of not doing a `realm.close()`? My database hasn't corrupted with or without the same.

Also, I've read that there are scenarios in which the Activity's `onDestroy()` may not get called at all. What effects the database can have in such a scenario if closing realm is so important?

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private static MyApp instance;
    private Realm realm;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .schemaVersion(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE)
                .migration(new RealmMigrationClass())
                .compactOnLaunch()
                .build());
        realm = Realm.getInstance(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration());
    }

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public Realm getRealm() {
        return realm;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        MyApp.getInstance().getRealm().close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Closing the realm instance is very important because of realm core has been written in c++ programming language and is compiled in the native code.And we know the c++ garbage collection does not run automatically we require to manually call the garbage collection.So when you call the **realm.close()** it means that realm deallocation the native memory means free or delete the pointer variable and also do the file descriptor job.From **realm.close()** means you give the command or tell to native c++ compiler to run the garbage collection.

Comment: But what are the repercussions of not doing a realm.close()? My database hasn't corrupted with or without the same.

Also, I've read that there are scenarios in which the Activity's onDestroy() may not get called at all. What effects the database can have in such a scenario?

Answer (score 2):

If you look the "doc" ([REALM_DOC](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)) for Realm for Java you can find:

> Realm implements Closeable to take care of native memory deallocation
>   and file descriptors, so always close your Realm instances when you’re
>   done with them.
>
> Realm instances are reference counted—if you call getInstance twice in
>   a thread, you need to call close twice as well. This allows you to
>   implement Runnable classes without having to worry about which thread
>   will execute them: simply start it with getInstance and end it with
>   close.

Personally I suggest you to define a class in which define your Realm functions and an "Realm attribute" (like a "RealmHelper" class) then inside this class define:
- a unstatic Realm 
- a static RealmHelper instance

You will always use this RealmHelper static instance for all operations in your Realm inside your main Thread, inside other threads you will call "new RealmHelper()" and CLOSE the realm just after you did the operation.

Doing this in your MainThread you just need to close ONE realm instance when the application get closed, to do this you can use the "Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks" interface inside a Custom defined Application class (so which extends Application of Android).

Example inside you Application custom class:

```
/* START Override ActivityLifecycleCallbacks Methods */
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        // Check if your MyRealmClass instance is null or is closed, in this case 
        // re-initialize it.
        if(MyRealmClass.getInstance() == null || MyRealmClass.getInstance().getRealm().isClosed()){
            MyRealmClass.initInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        if(!AppUtils.isAppOnForeground(this)){
            // Close your MyRealmClass instance
            if(MyRealmClass.getInstance() != null) {
                MyRealmClass.getInstance().close();
             MyRealmClass.getInstance().logRealmInstanceCount(LABEL_APP_IN_BACKGROUND);
                MyRealmClass.setMyInstance(null);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

    }
    /* END Override ActivityLifecycleCallbacks Methods */
```

Code of "isAppOnForeground" (check if your app is in foreground, if is not this mean your app is being closed):

```
public static boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
        boolean ret = false;
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if(appProcesses != null){
            String packageName = context.getPackageName();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
                if (appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                    ret = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Your "MyRealmClass" will look like:

```
public class MyRealmClass {

 protected Realm mRealm;
    protected static MyRealmClass mInstance;

    public MyRealmClass() {
        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    public static MyRealmClass initInstance(){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new MyRealmClass();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

public static MyRealmClass getInstance(){
        return mInstance;
    }

public static void setMyInstance(MyRealmClass instance) {
        mInstance = instance;
    }

public Realm getRealm() {
        return mRealm;
    }

    public void setRealm(Realm realm){
        this.mRealm = realm;
    }

public void close() {
        if (mRealm != null) {
            try {
                mRealm.close();
            } catch(Exception e){
                onException(e);
            }
        }
    }

[...]
```

Then you need to check that all your Realm instance is not closed when you use a RealmObject or you do some operation in your Realm. And if it is closed (because the app got in background and then restarted) you need to re-initialize the realm (if you have an activity with a MyRealmClass instance as attribute).
Example in a BaseMyActivity:

```
public abstract class MyBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected MyRealmClass mRealmClass;

    /* START Override Lifecycle Methods */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initMyRealmClass();
        Lyra.instance().restoreState(this, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        initMyRealmClass();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Lyra.instance().saveState(this, outState);
    }
    /* END Override Lifecycle Methods */

    /* START Private Methods */
    protected void initMyRealmClass(){
        if(mRealmClass == null || mRealmClass.getRealm().isClosed()){
            mRealmClass = MyRealmClass.initInstance();
        }
    }
    /* END Private Methods */

}
```

Basically all your activities will extend this BaseActivity if they need to use Realm functions. (Lyra is used to save the state of any of your attributes: [LYRA](https://github.com/Fondesa/Lyra))

## REMEMBER THAT:

if you set or get some attributes from a RealmObject or you get an object from a RealmList or RealmResults you NEED THAT YOUR REALM INSTANCE, from which the object was take, IS OPEN.
OTHERWISE you need to use this method when you init a variable with objects from the realm: (this methods should be placed in yuour "MyRealmClass")

```
public <T extends RealmObject> List<T> toList(RealmResults<T> results) {
            return mRealm.copyFromRealm(results);
        }

        public <T extends RealmObject> List<T> toList(RealmList<T> results) {
            return mRealm.copyFromRealm(results);
        }

        public <T extends RealmObject> T copyObjectFromRealm(T obj) {
            return mRealm.copyFromRealm(obj);
        }

    public <T extends RealmObject> RealmResults<T> findAllObject(Class<T> classObject) {
        RealmQuery<T> query = mRealm.where(classObject);
        return query.findAll();
    }
```

Now if you need to get a List of "MyRealmObjectClass" objects and add them to an adapter you will do this:

```
List<MyRealmObjectClass> myObjects = mRealmClass.toList(mRealmClass.findAllObject(MyRealmObjectClass.class))
myAdapter.addAll(myObjects);
```

Doing this if you "get" or "set" an attribute after the Realm instance, from which you got the objects, was closed (for example after the app get to background and then restarted) you won't get an exception.
BUT if you "set" an attribute of your RealmObject this WON'T BE SET in the REALM INSTANCE, so to change the value of a RealmObject inside the Realm in this case you need to Save the object!
OTHERWISE if you have a RealmResults or a RealmObject which is still connected to the Realm, so you can directly change, inside a transaction, an attribute of it and it will be changed inside the Realm too.
To do a Realm Transaction I suggest you to follow the DOC in the first link and, if you don't need to close the Realm in the Finally block, enable lambda and do this:

```
mRealm.executeTransaction(
    realm -> {
        [do your Realm operations]
    }
)
```

or you can also do:

```
public boolean doRealmOperation(Object... params){
AtomicBoolean ret = new AtomicBoolean(false);
mRealm.executeTransaction(
    realm -> {
        try{
            [do your realm operation]
            ret.set(true);
        } catch(Exception e){
           onException(e)
           ret.set(false);
        }
    }
)
}
```

in this case you need to use the "AtomicBoolean" because you will set the value you want to return inside the transaction, but inside a transaction the value got from outside of the transaction itself (in this case the "ret" variable) MUST BE A FINAL variable. But you can't define "ret" as "final" and then set it again, so you need to use the "AtomicBoolean" to set the variable outside the transaction and set it again inside the transaction itself. 
(You can also avoid this problem by using a temporary variable to get the "true/false" value inside the transaction and then set the "ret" variable using that "temp variable". But personally I prefer to use "AtomicBoolean" class which is, I think, safer and more clean than a temp variable)

Hope this is helpful,
see you by and happy coding! ;)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have already implement most of these and will try to implement the rest.

However, this still doesn't answer my original question: "What are the repercussions of not doing a realm.close()? My database hasn't corrupted with or without the same."

Imagine that your device's battery drains out while your realm based application was running. What happens now? Will the realm database corrupt because realm.close() wasn't called? If not, why do we even need realm.close()?

Comment: Hello, sorry for late answer I forgot about this post. Anyway I have answered on first lines of my post.
I think if you don't close you will have some low level memory management handler not closed, so in remote case this could cause problems (for example you fill all the pipe on which manage realms handler) and also you still have some memory used by not closed realm istance.

Also I supposed that a not closed Realm maybe could cause inconsistency inside the realm if you do some configuration changes on the realm but you don't update the configuration of others handlers opened.

Comment: Anyway these are just my opinion, I never had problem for a realm instance not closed and I didn't find any answer like "if you don't close realm instance your phone will explode..." lol
Just found inside the doc that is suggested/recommended to close all opened realm instance.

(Also i supposed that if you left realm instance opened and you use realm inside one or more applications this can take to strange behaviours because, maybe, on low level all the realm implementations of the apps use the same resources.)

Comment: So probably the problem is about low level android system resources begin not released by the not closed realm instances.

Hope this answered your question (I repeat that these are just my opinions and nothing that I found on the docs, so maybe I'm wrong)

Have a nice day and a nice coding :D
Greetings

Answer (score 1):

*Realm implements Closeable to take care of native memory deallocation and file descriptors, so always close your Realm instances when you’re done with them.*

*Realm instances are reference counted—if you call getInstance twice in a thread, you need to call close twice as well.*

From my personal experience not closing realm has not caused a lot of issues, in fact when I tried closing it at times it would cause an issue when the app went into the background and was then resumed which caused a crash due to realm instance being closed, I am not sure why a new instance of realm was not created in that case, might have been a bug.

As of now I follow the realm docs and close my realm instances until they cause an issue.

General coding practises suggest that anything that is opened should be safely closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will get closed only if you called **close()** method on your application's **destroy()** method. Remember **Realm implements Closeable** in order to take care of **native memory deallocation and file descriptors so it is important to close your Realm instances** when you are done with them.

For further info visit this [link.](https://realm.io/docs/java/0.75.0#closing-realm-instances)

Comment: "it will definitely get closed once you call the onDestroy() " - show some evidence for this

Comment: @NickCardoso, thank you for indicating that mistake, in my phone it's miui which is doing it but in normal android it has to be done manually, will be more careful next time.